# Optical Mouse Sensor Wiring

Tags: arduino, sensor, mouse

I'm trying to hack an optical mouse sensor: PAW3204DB. Here is the [datasheet](http://www.pixart.com.tw/upload/PAW3204DB_SPEC_V40_20091207_20100319090638.pdf). It has a voltage regulator, and I have no idea how to wire this to my arduino. I looked at a [different hack](http://www.martijnthe.nl/2009/07/interfacing-an-optical-mouse-sensor-to-your-arduino/) for an optical mouse sensor, but the wiring does not include a voltage regulator.

Does VDDA, pin 8 on the PAW3204WB, have to be wired to power? Which would mean:

- Pin 6 to Arduino GND
- Pin 7 to Arduino +5V
- Pin 8 to Arduino +5V
- 2 Serial pins to 2 other Arduino pins

Answer (score 2):

If you supply the 1V8 yourself, you can connect it to both VDDA and VDD. If you supply 2V5-2V9 (***not*** 5V), you can connect it to VDD and leave VDDA unconnected (or use it as a 1V8 source).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxnQVM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>